# How to open Instagram and other social media apps from webview in android

Tags: java, android, webview

I've created a simple app with webview. The website which I added in webview, has a range of social media. When I tap on the link one of them (Instagram for example) app opened in webview browser. After clicking on Open App, it shows me an error page. Can you help me with code lines that I can youse to solve this task and I could be redirected right to the app after clicking?
[image]

**My WebView code and error after clicking on Open App :**

[image]